# User Profile Synchronisation from SQL Database

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, sql-server, profile-sync

I am trying to update the Manager and Profile Picture properties for the UPS from SQL. The problem is that these two fields are stored as text in SQL but SharePoint expects a Person field and URL respectively. Has anyone been able to find a workaround to this?

Comment: How are you trying to update profile data? Via the object model or via the BCS?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am trying to do it via BCS. I have created and External Content Type that is pulls the data from SQL and added to my synchronisation connections. I can map fields like First Name, Last Name, Email Address etc without a problem but having a problem with the Manager and Picture fields. It appeats you cannot map text fields to these two?

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas indicates this is commonly done either by Creating a connection that imports the data from a BCS connection tied to a foriegn key like email address or account name. If coding is you thing you can use the SharePoint Object model to update the User Profile Properties my instantiating a UserProfileManager and then setting the properties. Either way you should never (ever) go directly to the SQL database.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain myself well. I am not doing it directly from SQL. I am using BCS. The problem comes when I try to map my Manager field (which is a text field in the External Content Type) to the Manager Property in UPS.